# MSP430 Assembly move contents of .data section to reserved space in address label

Tags: assembly, msp430, opcode, microprocessors

```
            .data
Vdata       .byte 7
Wdata       .word 10,-1
Xdata       .space      2
Ydata       .string "BA", "BY"
Zdata       .word 99h

            .sect "mysect"
Dest        .space      14
```

mysect is a section i have created assigned to the memory location 0x3400. I have created this space of 14 bytes inside of it. What I want to do is to move all the contents of the address labels declared above (Vdata to Zdata) to the 14 bytes space. Here is what I have tried:

```
            mov.b   Vdata, Dest
            mov.w   Wdata, Dest
            mov.w   Xdata, Dest
            mov.w   Ydata, Dest
            mov.w   Zdata, Dest
```

It only however updates the start of the memory location (0x3400).

UPDATE: I have tried other solutions but it does not work. I was wondering if someone had the code on how to perform what I need to do(move all values in the address labels to the space in mysect section).

Comment: You used the same store address every time, so that shouldn't be a surprise.  Use Dest+1, Dest+3, etc.  If MSP430 cares at all about alignment, then do mov.w for all of them without caring about whether the two bytes are from one object or not.  (And if `.data` is constant, use mov-immediate instead of a memory-memory copy.  Unless that's storing the addresses as immediate?)

Comment: If you read those `mov` instructions, the destination side is always `Dest`. Should sound logical, that it writes the source value every time to the same place. Also you are copying b+w+w+w+w data, which is only 9 bytes (if word is 16 bit, which I guess). The machine code and CPU doesn't see your source, so it has no idea how much data were defined after `Wdata` label, and that it should copy two words instead of one, you have to write code like that. There may be also automatic padding between V and W to make word aligned. Check probably some listing/disassembly to see how `.data` memory look

Comment: And indeed the `.word` directive does align data, so your `.data` segment should look after compilation as (hex bytes): `07 00 0A 00 FF FF 00 00 42 41 42 59 99 00` (14 bytes)